# Understanding Poisson Distribution Question?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following question:

[image]

I have the following formula:
[image]

However, it is unclear to me how to extract what I need.

Would U be equal to 17 for an average of 17 per minute and X be equal to 25?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The rate you need is $\lambda = \frac{170}{10}=17$ because you are interested in 1-minute intervals. Hence your distribution is $X \sim Poisson (17)$. Now what you need is the probability that there are more than $25$ requests in the system in one interval. The probability of this is 
$$
P(S)= 1-P(X \leq25)
$$
Can you handle from here?

Comment: Is it 1 - (p(0) + p(1) + p(2) ... p(25)) ? where x in the formula is p(x) ?

Comment: Don't forget $P(0)$ in your summation...

Comment: @Milo: yes it is

Comment: @Alex: Thanks:)

Comment: You are welcome